# Grails 3 eclipse support

Tags: eclipse, grails

i want to know if there any `Eclipse IDE` versions support `Grails 3.3.2` , as i'm currently using `Luna` and tried to use this Grails version but i faced the below error, also tried `Grails tool suite` and got the same error.  I tried it using `intellij` and worked fine without any exceptions

```
------System.err:-----------
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter
```

many are saying that eclipse doesn't supports `Grails 3` is that right ? and how to work with `Grails 3` on eclipse ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as Grails from the POV of IDE anymore. There is a `Gradle` project with a bunch of dependencies. That means that things like GGTS are not needed (and therefore not supported).

For my Grails projects I use Eclipse Oxygen with `Buildship` (gradle support) and `Groovy feature` plugins.

The only 2 things that I'm missing in my current setup is no autocomplete for dynamic finders and GSP. The rest works just fine.

Comment: what is the `Grails` version you are using ?

Comment: All from 3.0 to 3.3

Comment: Great , any tutorials to make `Grails` project using `Gradle` in eclipse ?

Comment: any recommendations ?

Comment: not that I know of. You just install the eclipse as per my post, and import your project as `gradle project` into.